# Debian. Issue with the ntfs after reloading from windows

Tags: windows, operating-system, debian, filesystems, ntfs

I have two systems on my laptop:

- Windows 8.2
- Debian 9

Sometimes (not all the time), I have some wieard problem:

After working on Windows system I load my Linux and some my partitions which formatted in NTFS have the read-only access for my User.

I cannot do some changes to the files on that disks by all users (besides the super admin).

Example:

> npm install -g something

- would not work.

> sudo nom install -g something

- would work.

In the some file explorer folders and files on that disks look's like locked, you know with the lock icon.

So, the question is - how to fix that issue? I want to use both systems for my work.

Maybe somebody here used to have the same problem.

Any advices are appritiate.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, if somebody will need the answer for this question, as I was needed.

Solution is to disable hibernation on windows.